# Can I use core entities in JDL Studio?

Tags: jhipster

I have a bunch of new entities defines but I want have a @OneToMany from User to one of these entities. Do I have to code it manually inside User or can I do it with the JDL studio ?

Answer (score 1):

User entity is an special entity. As you can read in the [JHipster documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/), not all types of relationships are allowed with User.

> Tip: the User entity
>
> Please note that the User entity, which is handled by JHipster, is
>   specific. You can do:
>
> **many-to-one relationships** to this entity (a Car can have a many-to-one relationship to a User). This will generate a specific
>   query in your new entity repository, so you can filter your entity on
>   the current security user, which is a common requirement. On the
>   generated Angular/React client UI you will have a dropdown in Car to
>   select a User.
>
> **many-to-many and one-to-one relationships** to the User entity, but the other entity must be the owner of the relationship (a Team can
>   have a many-to-many relationship to User, but only the team can
>   add/remove users, and a user cannot add/remove a team). On the
>   Angular/React client UI, you will also be able to select a User in a
>   multi-select box.
>
> When using the UAA authentication type, you can only create
>   relationships to the User entity if the related entity is also within
>   the UAA microservice.

Comment: it seems that for ManyToMany it doesn't add the 'current user' specific queries

Comment: btw in those findByXXXIsCurrentUser() methods,  where does it get the principle.username from for the query ?   e.g. `select ...where .....login = ?#{principal.username}"`